# Deleting Sharepoint Sites taking too much time

Tags: 2007, my-site, site-collection, web, tools

I am trying to delete few sites that have loads of sub-sites but its taking way too much time,

I tried to delete sites using "Content Structure" & tried to use this tool as well,

[Tool for deleting sites](http://spstipsutilitypack.codeplex.com/)

both option do work , but take too much time, is there alternative or quickest way of doing it.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the stsadm [deletesite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261873%28v=office.12%29.aspx) option or do it within central administration for faster site collection removal.  Do you have access to either of those?

Comment: +1 Deletion operation via GUI can also causes timeouts some times. So best is stsadm

Comment: Depending on how much content resides in the site, that is a valid point.

Answer (score 2):

The faster method to delete site is through STSADM for MOSS 2007 and SharePoint 2010 Management Shell for SharePoint 2010.